# How do I use auto layout to start a view in the half of its superview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, autolayout

I have a view inside a view:

```
+--------------+
|              |
|       +-----+|
|       |     ||
|       +-----+|
+--------------+
```

I’d like the inner view to always start right in the middle of the outer view horizontally, and span the whole remaining half to the right edge:

```
innerView.frame.size.width = outerView.frame.size.width/2;
innerView.frame.origin.x = outerView.frame.size.width/2;
```

How can I express that using auto layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in Interface Builder, but this is pretty easy to do by creating the constraints in code.

Your first equation is exactly how I would express the constraint. The second equation might work, but it is weird to relate an origin to a width. They are different quantities. Instead, just pin the right of the innerView to the right of the outerView.

We use the attribute `NSLayoutAttributeTrailing` instead of `NSLayoutAttributeRight`, so your interface will properly flip when localized RTL.

```
// innerView.width = outerView.width * 0.5
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:innerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:outerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                            multiplier:0.5
                              constant:0];

// innerView.trailing = outerView.trailing
NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:innerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:outerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];

[outerView addConstraints:@[widthConstraint, rightConstraint]];
```

Answer (score 16):

You actually can do this in IB/Storyboards as far back as Xcode 5.1 (potentially earlier)

1. Create a width constraint between the view and the super view
2. Set it's relationship to "Equal"
3. Set it's constant to "0"
4. **Set it's multiplier to "2:1" or "1:2"** (depending on item order in the constraint)

IB, apparently, only allows multipliers to be set to integers or ratios, not floating point numbers. Here's a screen cap for more clarity

[image: Constraint setting for width half it's parent]

Note: if "First Item" and "Second Item" are flipped, the ratio is "2:1"

Comment: How does one add such constraints?

Comment: Are you asking for more detail on step 1? If so, one way of doing this would be to ctrl+click+drag between the subview and its super view and select "Equal Widths". This will create a width constraint with a ratio of 1:1, you will then need to select the newly created constraint (either from the view tree on the left or from the size inspector of either of the two views), and change the multiplier as detailed above

Comment: That option is disabled, or actually not even there for me. I only see leading/trailing space 'n stuff... :/

Comment: You could also select both views, click the pin menu in the bottom right corner, and select "Equal Widths"

Comment: For some reason that option is always disabled. And I can't figure out why. I'm in a XIB, not a storyboard if that makes any difference. My superview is the content view of a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Ah. Yes I'm seeing that issue also. Placing your content view subviews in a wrapper view seems to open up that option between subviews and the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can put into mid of the parent view and remove all autolayout settings in interface builder. It will be always in same position event if you will rotate it.